# Can't npm install webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I can't get webpack-dev-server installed:

```
npm install -g webpack-dev-server
```

and I get:

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@1.2.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bufferutil package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bufferutil
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\...\npm-debug.log
```

Do I need python installed? How can I get it done? Is it a problem with bufferutil package?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, (node-)gyp needs pyhton 2 installed. What platform are you on?

Comment: My app is running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

From speaking with a friend here at work, this isn't an issue. We don't need Python at all.

I'll look into this more. So far I have installed and run, but mine doesn't quite work. It tries to load the page and then fails with a single warning about combiner.

```
/deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.
```

Here is a small timeline of problems and fixes I ran into to get it working properly. Reloads seem much slower than i thought it should be!

```
 1. 

Problem: Stuck pulling http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/

fix: http://127.0.0.1:8080/

 2. 

Problem: which didn't allow for watch to reupdate

Fix:  change entry in webpack.config.js to entry: [
    "./app.js",
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', ] and include 
        <script src="https://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script> to the index.html and run webpack-dev-server --inline

 3. 

Problem: Then started getting: Errors while compiling. App updated with errors. No reload!     multi main Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server' in C:\Users\KRebstock\Desktop\reactexamples\webpack example1 resolve module webpack/hot/only-dev-server in C:\Users\KRebstock\Desktop\reactexamples\webpack example1  @ multi main

Fix:   removed
     'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', from  webpackage.config.js  in  entry: ["bla","bla"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install it without post-install scripts (`npm i -g webpack-dev-server --ignore-scripts`). It will work this way.